# Group $U$ of $p$-adic units is inverse limit of $U/U_{n}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In Serre's famous Course in Arithmetic, there is a somewhat unexplained claim:

> Let $U=\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times}$ be the group of $p$-adic units. For every $n\geq 1$, put $U_{n}=1+p^{n}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$; this is the kernel of the homomorphism $\epsilon_{n}\colon U\to(\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. In particular, the quotient $U/U_{1}$ can be identified with $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times}$, hence is cyclic of order $p-1$. The $U_{n}$ form a decreasing sequence of open subgroups of $U$, and $U=\varprojlim U/U_{n}$.

I'm trying to get a grip on the details and got a little lost in the very last assertion.

I'm guessing I am not supposed to show two-sides inclusions, but to use some diagram property.

We do not know yet that $U\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, so Serre got me lost in what to do to justify such a thing.

How can I justify this equality?

Also, is there an analogous phenomena involving general inverse limits of rings? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\mathbf Z_p = \varprojlim \mathbf Z/p^n \mathbf Z$ (inverse limit of rings), so naturally $U$ : = $\mathbf Z^*_p = \varprojlim (\mathbf Z/p^n \mathbf Z)^*$ (inverse limit of groups). With your notations: $U/U_n = (\mathbf Z/p^n \mathbf Z)^*$, so  $\varprojlim U/U_n = \mathbf Z^*_p$ . One could also argue directly that $\varprojlim U_n = 1$ (obvious) and take the inverse limit of the exact sequences $1-->U_n-->U--> U/U_n-->1$ to get $U =\varprojlim U/U_n$ (the inverse limit is a right exact functor) . The connecting morphisms are inclusion for the $U_n$'s and identity for $U$ .